# The difference between the self-created interfaces and ready interfaces

Tags: java, interface, overriding

I have a question regarding Interfaces.

For example, when I create an interface and this interface has three different abstract methods. The class, which implements this interface, has to have these methods in the class to write a body for them. However, when I implement a ready interface, I do not need to write a body for the methods, which this specific interface has. For example, in case I implement the "clonable" interface in my class, I do not have to write a body for the method "clone", which is defined in cloneable interface. Why is it so?

Thank you for your time and interest.

Comment: No, I do not extend.

Comment: For the record, `Cloneable` doesn't define any methods. `clone` is a protected method in `Object`, so since it's not abstract, your class is not required to override it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces without methods are called "marker" interfaces in Java.
The [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) and [`Cloneable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interfaces are examples of such interfaces.

Quoting from [Wikipedia page on marker interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern):

> Whereas a typical interface specifies functionality (in the form of
>   method declarations) that an implementing class must support, a marker
>   interface need not do so. The mere presence of such an interface
>   indicates specific behavior on the part of the implementing class.

[`Closeable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) on the other hand is *not* such an interface:
it defines a `close()` method, which you must implement.

Comment: Actually, I chose my example wrong. I did it with "cloneable" interface and had not to write any body for the methods, which "cloneable" has, and thought that I have learnt the interfaces false. I edit my example in the question. Thank you for the answer. I will research this "marker" interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you are implementing the Closeable interface directly, you are required to implement `close()`.

If you are extending a class that already implements `close()`, then the contract has been fulfilled by your superclass and you do not need to override it.

From Oracle's docs:

> If your class claims to implement an interface, all methods defined by that interface must appear in its source code before the class will successfully compile.

Link here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: Even if you implement it directly (that is, your class contains `implements Closeable`), you still don't need to provide a definition for `close()` if a superclass already does.

Comment: I realize that I misread the question, which uses "Cloneable" as an example, not "Closeable". My mistake!

Comment: Ha! Me too. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an example will explain this better, see below.

It does not matter whether you have declared an interface or someone else. To *instantiate* an object it must have a concrete type, i.e. it cannot have any abstract methods. A class has abstract methods if it itself qualifies any methods as `abstract` or if it does not implement any abstract method it inherits from its super class or super interface, going up in the inheritance hierarchy.

```
interface A{
    void method1();
    void method2();
}

abstract class B1 implements A {
    // B1 must be declared abstract as it does not provide implementation of method2
    @Override public void method1() {}
}

class B2 extends B1{
    @Override public void method2() {}
}

class B3 extends B2{
    static void bar(){
        B1 b1 = new B1(); // ERROR B1 is abstract
        B1 b2 = new B2(); // OK, all methods of A are implemented
        B1 b3 = new B3(); // as above
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is a great example. This example also answers my question but these "marker" interface were confusing point for me.